# NodeJS - 'Error: Invalid URI "/"'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, request-promise

I'm using request-promise to request two JSON data files which exist locally in my local project directory folder.
ie:

[image]

However, I am getting a 500 internal server error, when trying to pass the data to the view and my node console outputs `'Error: Invalid URI "/"',`

Please see below:

**server.js**

```
    let express = require('express');
    let app = express();
    let path = require('path');
    const rp = require("request-promise");

    //STORE PATH for local JSON files on variables
    let guest = require('./public/data/Companies');
    let hotel = require('./public/data/Guests');

    app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

    //GET JSON
    //Question: Is it okay to pass uri:guest
    app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
        Promise.all([rp({uri: guest, json: true}), rp({uri: hotel, json: true})]).then(function([hotels, guests]) {
            //res.json({hotels, guests});
            res.send({hotels, guests});
            console.log(hotels, guests);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).end();
        });
    });


    //CATCHALL
    app.get("/*", function(req,res){
        let file = req.params[0] || "/views/index.html";
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/public/", file));
    });

    //SET PORT
    app.listen(app.get("port"), function(){
        console.log("Listening on port: " , app.get("port"));
    });
```

then on **client.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/data",
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you simply returning the variables?

I mean:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    res.send({hotels, guests}); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use request to get the data? Why don't you use the filesystem module from Node.js (`fs`) to get the data? When you call `rp()`, you should pass an absolute URI and not a local path.

To use it in your code, you need to "promisify" the readFile function:

```
let readFileAsAPromise = function(filename){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(filename, (data, err) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

You can then you `Promise.all`.

Comment: Cld you pls post an example using (fs) to get both of the json files? @Olivier Liechti